# Why my website connects to database on local server, but it does not connect on university domain?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have been testing my dummy website if it connects to database on my localhost server. It works perfectly fine (I use MAMP on my mac). I can enter details in simple form, send it and the database updates just like it should do.

When I uploaded my website to university domain, and changed values in my php code according to the details of that domain, for some reason the website does not connect to the database and it won't update.

Here is the form that I use in HTML:

```
                        <!-- Contact Form -->
                    <section>
                        <form method="post" action="connection.php">
                            <div class="row gtr-50">
                                <div class="col-6 col-12-small">
                                    <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" placeholder="Full Name" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-6 col-12-small">
                                    <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" placeholder="Email" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <textarea name="Review" id="Review" placeholder="Your review about meals" rows="4"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <ul class="actions">
                                        <li>
                                            <input type="submit" class="style1" value="Send" />
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <input type="reset" class="style2" value="Reset" />
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </section>
```

Here is the PHP code to connect to database (on localhost everything connects perfectly fine, of course I changed the variables like $servername = "localhost"; $username = "root" etc. )
[my php code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkO1w.png)

Now when I open website on university domain, fill up that form and send it, this is what I get: [picture of connection error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUSNP.png)

I have tried to change servername, username, password, etc variables and it still doesn't work. I'm guessing that I'm missing something really silly here, as on localhost everything works well.

Here are my university domain details: [university domain details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sak4s.png)

Here are the database I am trying to connect website to details:[database details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W56Iv.png)

P.S sorry for my English as it is not my first language, hope I was clear enough about the issue.

Comment: Your website and database running on same server?

Comment: On your database detail what info do you see on clicking **Connection Info**

Comment: @BanujanBalendrakumar Yes, everything is running on PLESK, not sure if you heard about it. But you manage your website, database etc on that platform.

Comment: @NishantSaini Hi, thanks for asking. Connection info shows this info: 
Host: 172.16.11.22:3306
Database name: rana1_17_DB1
User name: rana1_DB1
Password: ******

Comment: That is what you have to use to connect to the DB and not the plesk login password. Also `$servername` should be `172.16.11.22`

Comment: @NishantSaini Thank you so much for your help! This is my first attempt to use php and databases, rookie mistakes:)

Answer (score 1):

> First Do not share Sensitive information Like `IP` and `Username`.
>
> Check user privilege and permissions. If everything is okay, Reason is below...

**The reason is,** By default, MySQL will not accept connection which is coming from outside of the server. It will not accept connection if you use `IP or Domain` instead of `localhost` Even your `application/website` and `database` hosted on `Same Server`.

**Solution**

If your Site/App and Database are hosted in same server, You should use `localhost` as host name instead of the `Domain` or `IP`. In your case remove IP `172.16.xx.xx` and use `localhost`.

If not,
You should enable remote connection and tell MySQL to allow the connection which is coming from Application server **ONLY** (For Security)

**1. cPanel**

You can enable remote access in your `cPanel`. 
[connect-to-databases-remotely-in-cpanel-hosting-16103](https://sg.godaddy.com/help/connect-to-databases-remotely-in-cpanel-hosting-16103)

**2. Using SSH (In Dedicated Servers)**

[Enable MySQL remote connection Ubuntu Server](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-set-up-mysql-for-remote-access-on-ubuntu-server-16-04/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your thorough answer and your time! I'm just starting to learn all of this stuff and glad I could find help!

Comment: @Aurimas You are always welcome. Welcome to stackoverflow